# Perfect forwarding vs const reference

Tags: c++, reference, rvalue, perfect-forwarding

I have a simple question I do not understand

```
int solution(int&& a, int&& b);

int main() {
    int a, b;
    std::cin >> a >> b;
    std::cout << solution(std::forward<int>(a), std::forward<int>(b)) << std::endl;
}

int solution(int&& a, int&& b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

I am a Java developer and started to re-learn C++ from my University background level and I always see "&&" after the any type, I've learnt that that is a rvalue reference, then I've learnt about move constructors etc. I just do not understand clearly what does `std::forward` do beyond the scenes? Does it really give the rvalue reference so no copy of argument is created? If that is right why is it better than writing just `const int&`? (I do not copy anything here either).

Comment: Have you read https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward? `std::forward` is used only with [forwarding references](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#Forwarding_references) — roughly meaning a function parameter `T&&` where `T` is a type parameter of the function template.

Comment: Perfect forwarding is with template functions and `&&` parameters.  In a non-template function `&&` parameters bind to rvalue arguments.  (At one time the term *universal reference* was used, but that has generally fallen out of favor.)

Comment: Thank u guys, I think I need more reading about perfect forwarding....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does it really give the rvalue reference so no copy of argument is created?

Yes.

> If that is right why is it better than writing just const int&?(I do not copy anything here either.

It isn't.

In fact, for a simple `int`, you shouldn't even be passing by reference. They're small enough that a nice simple pass-by-copy is preferable (and, oddly, perhaps easier to optimise).

Rvalue references are useful for implementing move semantics (with classes that have indirect resources that can be transferred) and perfect forwarding, not for simple non-mutating function arguments.

Your example has nothing to do with perfect forwarding; it's just passing a reference to a function.

> I always see "&&" after the any type

You shouldn't see it "always".